# Wierd glitch on my monitor

Tags: display

So when I open file explorer red dots start to appear on the left side of the screen and they kinda flicker this goes away if I exit fullscreen and I've never seen this anywhere else on my computer.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Can you recall when this started happening relative to any significant changes in your computer?

Comment: @Romen Well we moved my PC to another place we also cleaned the monitor, but I don't think it's the monitor's problem. Here's a photo (since when I try to screenshot it goes away) https://imgur.com/a/rXfMLQi